# What are these called? Is it appropriately correct to say "cluster glissandi"?

Tags: terminology, glissando

[image: sample]

This is from Prokofiev's piano concerto number 3, the third movement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wikipedia refers to these as "double-note arpeggi":

> Then the coda explodes into a musical battle between soloist and orchestra, with prominent piano ornamentation over the orchestra (including famously difficult double-note arpeggi, sometimes approximated by pianists with keyboard glissandos using the knuckles)

There is a notated glissando earlier in the movement, one bar before rehearsal mark 98.

[image: glissando]

The double-note passages are clearly notated, rather than marked as glissandi, so it's clear that Prokofiev's intent was literal.

The fingering given in the [Russian "Collected Works"](https://imslp.simssa.ca/files/imglnks/usimg/f/f7/IMSLP66126-PMLP04522-Prokofiev_-_Piano_Concerto_No._3,_Op._26_(orch._score).pdf) at rehearsal mark 137 reinforces Prokofiev's intent.

[image: double-note arpeggio]

Each double-note is to be played with a single finger, and each ascending and descending section comprises ten note-units (either singleton or double), thus being "playable" by the two hands acting side-by-side as ten fingers. ("Playable" being a relative term.)

The Isidor Philipp edition<sup>1</sup> features an even less plausible fingering (IMO):

[image: Philipp edition fingering]

---

In this video of [Martha Argerich with the Singapore Symphony](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BS0SwRoYAW0&t=28m58s), you can see her hands when she first encounters the double-note arpeggi (28:58). She uses a hand-over-hand technique. However, at 29:08 she uses a side-by-side technique. 1000 bonus points to anyone who can figure out what she's actually doing. :-)

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Serge Prokofieff, "Concerto No. 3 (1917-21)", ed. Isidor Philipp (1956, International Music Company).</sub>

Comment: TIL about single-finger double-note!  Any other composers who instructed performers to use this technique?

Comment: My fingers DO NOT WANT to play arpeggios on the cracks. I've been trying to MAKE them for some considerable time today, but they refuse. I had always heard these as glissandi. Seeing the music I assumed the fingering showed what *one* hand was doing but left the other hand up to the pianist. One hand was therefore on top of the other. I had some - modest - success playing it like that. But you are right. The glorious Martha Argerich (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BS0SwRoYAW0) is playing it correctly (at 28'58"). At this stage I generally point out I'm primarily a composer, not a pianist. :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft One of the more commonly encountered examples (at least in my experience) is Chopin's [Prelude in A Major](https://imslp.simssa.ca/files/imglnks/usimg/5/5b/IMSLP127820-WIMA.af06-Chopin_Prelude_Amajor.pdf), Op. 28 No. 7. In m. 12 there is a chord requiring the two lowest right-hand notes (A# and C#) to be played with the thumb. The Prokofiev technique, however, I've not encountered before.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian Wow. I listened to a different video that showed the score, so I presumed she was using the "knuckle technique" mentioned in the Wikipedia description.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I've never seen *quite* this technique. Seconds played by the thumb are common enough though. (Debussy's Feux d'Artifice prelude and Bartok's Dance Suite eg.)